# Propositional logic: entailment and satisfiability

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I'm trying to prove the following result for formula $F$ and set of formulas $\mathcal{S}$:

$\mathcal{S} \models F\Rightarrow \exists \mathcal{S}_0 ⊆ S$ (finite) such that $\mathcal{S}_0 \models F$

Take $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{S})=1$ so that $\mathcal{A}(F)=1$. By the compactness theorem, there is finite $\mathcal{S}_0 ⊆ S$ which is also satisfiable; indeed, we can say $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{S}_0) = 1$ by the fact that $\mathcal{S}_0 ⊆ S$.

If what I have done is correct (I'm not sure) then I believe what we are looking for is to ensure that all other assignments such that $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{S}_0) = 1$ also give $\mathcal{A}(F) = 1$. However, I'm really not sure how to do this and was wondering if anyone could help? Thanks!

Comment: But you have to prove that $\mathcal A$ satisfies also $F$...

Comment: You have to consider $S \cup \{ \lnot F \}$, which is *unsatisfiable* and apply the Compactness Th to it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok, that $S \cup \lbrace{ \neg F \rbrace}$ makes sense - thank you!